# Almost surely uniform convergence using ergodic Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, uniform-convergence, ergodic-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I have a question rearding the almost surely uniform convergence using ergodic Theorem.

Let  $\left\lbrace X_t\right\rbrace_t$ be a stationnary ergodic process. By the ergodic theorem, we have as $m\to\infty$
$$\dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{t=1}^m X_t\longrightarrow \mathbb{E} X_1\;\;\; a.s. $$

Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denote the flooring perator, i.e., the largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$.

My question is, by the above convergence how can we prove the following  convergence, as $m\to\infty$
$$\sup\limits_{\tau\in\Pi}| \dfrac{1}{\lfloor m\tau\rfloor}\sum_{t=1}^{\lfloor m\tau\rfloor}X_t-\mathbb{E} X_1|\longrightarrow 0\;\;\;a.s $$
with $\Pi\subset [0,1]$?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Is $\Pi$ an arbitrary subset of $[0,1]$? For $\Pi = [0,1]$ this should not hold : Take $X_i$ iid, then for $\tau =\frac 1 m$ the $\sup$ is always bigger than $\lvert X_1 - \mathbb E X_1\rvert$ which does not go to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Indeed, $\Pi$ is any sub-interval strictly included in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for $\Pi=(a,1]$ with $0<a<1$. Indeed, if $\tau\in (a,1]$, then  $\lfloor m\tau\rfloor$ necessarily belongs to $\left\{\lfloor ma\rfloor,\dots,m\right\}$ hence
$$
\sup\limits_{\tau\in\Pi}\left| \dfrac{1}{\lfloor m\tau\rfloor}\sum_{t=1}^{\lfloor m\tau\rfloor}X_t-\mathbb{E} X_1\right|
\leqslant \max_{\lfloor ma\rfloor\leqslant \ell\leqslant m}\left|\frac 1\ell\sum_{t=1}^\ell X_t-\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]\right|\leqslant 
\sup_{\ell\geqslant\lfloor ma\rfloor}\left|\frac 1\ell\sum_{t=1}^\ell X_t-\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]\right|,
$$
which goes to $0$ almost surely by the ergodic theorem.

As pointed out by Stefan, the wanted convergence does not hold if $\Pi=[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer.